# Can race condition occur in below code

Tags: java, multithreading

Could a race codition occur when invoking method addId from multiple threads ?

```
private static Map<String , Long> table;

static {
    table = new ConcurrentHashMap<String  , Long>();
}

public static void addId(String key, Long value){

    if(table.containsKey(key)){
        table.remove(key);
    }

    table.put(key, value);
}
```

Comment: You can declare `table` in one line.

Comment: Declaring on one line is same as declaring within static class code ?

Comment: yes, but it takes one line instead of four. I would also make the `table` `final`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nothing prevents another thread from putting some value between the `containsKey`/`remove` and the `put`, so checking if the table already contains a key before putting isn't really "safe" (or rather, doesn't really "make sense").

Why don't you just do

```
public static void addId(String key, Long value){
    table.put(key, value);
}
```

`put` will override any previous entry anyway.

---

If you don't want multiple threads to execute the method concurrently, declare the method as `synchronized`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

(It seems that my answer has to be 30 characters or more)

The `addId` call can gave a race condition: one thread can try to put a key and another can remove the a key at the same time (if it's the same key, then it could be a problem). Within that method there are a couple more cases in which you can get a race condition (with various consequences).

This may further be complicated if you have other methods that do other things with the table, i.e. read from it, and it will make your race condition much worse than "just" an overwritten value.

Ultimately, what are you asking? Are you wondering how to avoid the race condition? What does the rest of your map class do?

Comment: The rest of the class just has an accessor method which returns a value from the table Map

Comment: I'm wondering how to avoid the race condition, apologies if my question a seemed a bit vague. It's more than answered, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a race condition could occur.

```
   if(table.containsKey(key)){
        table.remove(key);
    }

    table.put(key, value);
```

Another thread could modify the table between your containsKey, the remove and the put. There's no need to call remove() before doing the put(), though - remove the containsKey / remove and it will be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to guarantee something is done with the old value when it is replaced, then the race could result in not handling all the overwritten keys.

```
if(table.containsKey(key)){
    Long oldValue = table.remove(key);
}
table.put(key, value);
if (oldValue != null)
    importantOperation(oldValue);
```

**Edit:**

It looks like [put](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) also returns the old value if there was one, so the check is still not necessary (as others have specified).  The check would be necessary in the following awkward situation, which would have racing involved:

```
if(table.containsKey(key)){
    Long oldValue = table.remove(key);
    value = secretlyAdjustInput(oldValue, value)
}
table.put(key, value);
```